# How to refresh claims from Identity Server 4 AFTER profile update?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, identityserver4

I'm using aspnet core 1.1 and Identity Server 4. I've created a policy in my client Startup.cs that denied all non-verified email accounts to use some sections of the website.

Here's the code of my policy:

```
//Add policies
services.AddAuthorization(authorizationOptions =>
{
    authorizationOptions.AddPolicy(
        ApplicationGlobals.Policy_HasValidatedAccount,
        policyBuilder =>
        {
            policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            policyBuilder.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified, "true", 
            ClaimValueTypes.Boolean);
        });
});
```

The question is: How can I refresh this `EmailVerified` claim AFTER the user a confirmed his account? The only way I found was to logout / login ...

Answer (score 4):

If the information you are checking against is in the token, then yes the only way to get a new token is a new token request (aka authentication).

If you need something more dynamic, don't use data from a token.

https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/